# Unintentional Lies and Misinformation

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine a scenario where Jim provides a piece of information to Sue. Jim believes this information to be true and correct, but is later proven to be mistaken. Some might say that Jim lied to Sue. I believe this to be the wrong word, because the misinformation was unintentional.

Is there a better word for this type of unintentional "lie"?

Comment: There is no such thing as an unintentional lie.

Comment: True, a lie is a falsehood.  But asserting a falsehood while believing it to be true is not the *act* of lying.  It is being mistaken.

Comment: There is a vast [pragmatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics) literature on this, under the rubrics of [presupposition](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuppositiontriggers.pdf), [implicature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature), [entailment](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/predicatetypes.pdf), [invited inference](http://www.stanford.edu/~zwicky/on-invited-inferences.pdf), [assertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_assertion), and [speech acts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_acts). Among others.

Comment: @tchrist, if I wake up in the morning and my nightstand clock says it's 7:15 in the morning, but because I forgot about daylight savings time it is actually 8:15, asserting to my wife that it is 7:15 might be a lie, but it is unintentional.  I don't know where you get the idea that there's no such thing as an unintentional lie.  If I didn't intend to state a falsehood as true, it's unintentional.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: but that's the point - if it's unintentional, it fails the criteria for being a lie. The *definition* of "lie" includes intent.

Comment: No, it doesn't, @Marthaª.  A falsehood is a lie.  But uttering a falsehood is the act of lying only if the utterer is aware that that which is uttered is false.  I was born on October 3.  If you think I was born on October 4, then you are not lying to state what you think, but the fact you utter is a lie.  The noun "lie" is only related to the verb "to lie" -- they are not the same thing.  "Lying" is uttering lies while believing that they are false.  A "lie" is anything false.

Comment: You have it backwards: if the fact I utter is untrue, it's a lie if and only if I know that it is untrue. Otherwise, it's merely an untrue statement.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist The OED, like any other dictionary, defineds a *lie* as *“a false statement **made with intent to deceive”***.  Without intent to deceive, it is not a lie.  It just isn’t true, is all.  The opposite of true is not lie but false.

Comment: The above commentary is *exactly* what makes Amish Programmer's question relevant.  It is phrased correctly, and even has the quotes around the word lie.

Comment: Not sure why I can't "Answer" (I have 100 pts..).  But a lie and a falsehood are not the same -- a lie can be based on a very true statement which is true either by intent (a white lie) or by accident (the fact you thought was untrue turned out to be true, but your intent was to utter a false or deceptive statement).  I would say that Jim said something that turned out not to be true. Shortened to 'told her something wrong or a falsehood.  If it wasn't a lie, Jim told sue the truth.  Notice that there isn't a 'single word' for that either.  Just for lie.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right to avoid "unintentional lie", because it's an oxymoron.

> **[lie](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lie)** n.
>   1. A false statement deliberately presented as being true; a falsehood.
>   2. Something meant to deceive or give a wrong impression.

As you can see, without the intent to deceive, it can't be called a "lie".

"Falsehood" technically sounds like it could be the neutral word you want, but most people use it as a synonym of "lie".

> **[falsehood](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/falsehood)** n.
>   1. An untrue statement; a lie.
>   2. The practice of lying.
>   3. Lack of conformity to truth or fact; inaccuracy.

OK, so **inaccuracy** is pretty good: the information is wrong, but the conveyor of the information isn't being accused of anything. A similar word would be **untruth**.

If what you want is a *verb*, it's a bit more difficult. You're pretty much stuck rephrasing:

> Jim told Sue that [...], but he was mistaken.

> Jim unintentionally gave Sue false information.

Comment: Untruth suffers from the same quality as falsehood -- its meaning can incorporate the unintentional, but is usually associated with a lie.

Answer (score 0):

Jim **misled** Sue. He didn't "lie" to her (because that was not his intent) but he *did* give her misleading information.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lie

LIE

1a : an assertion of something known or believed by the speaker to be untrue with intent to deceive

1b : an untrue or inaccurate statement **that may or may not be believed true by the speaker**

2 : some[THING] that misleads or deceives

Comment: Wow -- voted down without comments, despite providing a well known source's definition that includes no intent (for the noun form, not the verb form).  Hopefully the vote down was because of a lack of explanation.

Answer (score -1):

The word you're looking for is "Confabulation".

Comment: Your answer would be improved with a link to a dictionary, an explanation of the meaning of this word, and why you think that this word meets the requirement spelled out in the question.

Comment: As for the merits of the word itself -- Aside from the 'informal chat' definition which doesn't apply, the relevent one seems to only apply in psychiatry -- the filling in of memory gaps with false facts taken as true.  Not even close to providing an answer.