# Verb for unintentionally 'lying'

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, vocabulary

Is there a verb to describe the act of telling a lie unintentionally?

Lying is not telling the truth intentionally as far as I know, but what if someone makes a mistake when telling a testimony in court or forgets a certain detail when describing something unintentionally?

Comment: Very closely related: [unintentional lies and misinformation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142649/unintentional-lies-and-misinformation).

Comment: Isn't that a 'mistake'?

Answer (score 2):

Although I really like the '**confabulate**' from the other answer, if you are intending to use this in a more casual context, might I suggest **misspeak**, defined at [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misspeak) thus:

> *misspeak* verb [ I ] ... mainly US
>
> ​ to say something that is not correct, by mistake:
>
> *The Secretary denied lying, but said that he misspoke.*

So you'd have exchanges like

> A: You told me you'd be here at 11, where were you?
>   B: I could have sworn it was 12, I must have misspoken. I'm so sorry.

Comment: But isn't "misspeak" a matter of _saying something different than what you meant to say_? That's not the same as unintentional lying. E.g. if I am honestly convinced that Julius Caesar was the first President of the United States, and I explicitly state that as a fact, I did not misspeak (I said what I wanted to say), but I unintentionally said something that is not true.

Comment: I feel like 'misspeak' can apply both to cases of accidental mispronunciations as well as situations where the belief at the time did not turn out to correspond to fact (and that the quoted dictionary definition includes both cases).

Comment: @Flater Is it? Not according to CED. But I'm not saying that what you say here is not true. You need to add an alternative definition.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "by mistake" is ambiguous. Is it a mistake of _speaking_ or a mistake of _being wrong_? The definition doesn't disambiguate that, but the word "misspeak" does disambiguate it, in my opinion. It clearly points at the mistake occuring in **speaking**. Also, the A/B example is clearly a case of this, as B **meant** 12 but **said** 11.

Comment: @Flater [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misspeak) clearly  includes both the faulty delivery and the faulty content senses. CED gives only the latter: ​ 'to say something that is [in]correct' **not** ​ 'to say something [in]correct[ly], [in an incorrect style]': But both are endorsed by Webster's.  Disambiguation is often required in English –  it's a fact of life.

Answer (score -1):

There is a psychology term called **confabulation**. Although formally it is concerned with memory disturbances leading to misinformation (see definition below), in practice it is used for any unintended lying, such as due to a **delusion** - also a viable answer.

In psychiatry, confabulation (verb: **confabulate**) is a disturbance of memory, defined as the production of fabricated, distorted, or misinterpreted memories about oneself or the world, without the conscious intention to deceive
.
*Confabulation - Wikipedia
Wikipedia › wiki › Confabulation*

"The alcoholic told his wife he only had one drink; he **confabulated**, not remembering anything after the first."

**Delusion** definition, meaning, what is delusion : belief in something that is not true: **to delude oneself**

*Cambridge English Dictionary*

"He is deluded into thinking the sun sets in the east. He told all who would listen of his revelation."

Comment: No. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confabulate) has: 'A major characteristic of brain-damaged patients is the tendency to confabulate' —to hide and dissemble about their damage.'—Peter R. Breggin. Dissimulation is deliberate.

Comment: A confabulate will fill in the missing part of his memory with whatever sounds reasonable. Thus, on the vast majority of times where the information is untrue, and unintentionally so, __confabulate__ fits the OP's question.

Comment: Not 'but what if someone makes a mistake when telling a testimony in court or forgets a certain detail when describing something, unintentionally?' This is hardly specifying a medical disorder. 'Confabulation is a clinical syndrome resulting from injury to the brain.' {[Memorylossonline.com/glossary](http://www.memorylossonline.com/glossary/confabulation.html)}